# Tensorflow on Raspberry pi for image processing

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, raspberry-pi, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I want to use Raspberry pi for taking pictures and then process them through Tensorflow (train it to find that object in an image and count it) to count my objects for example. I couldn't find any example, do you know if this is possible? I know OpenCV maybe easier but do you know if this is possible with Tensorflow?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't train a TensorFlow model on a Raspberry Pi, there simply isn't the processing power. However, you could train a TensorFlow model on a laptop/PC and then deploy the model on a Raspberry Pi to do object recognition.

Have a read of this blog post on Pyimagesearch, there are some really in depth tutorials on TensorFlow/Keras on Raspberry Pi.

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/12/18/keras-deep-learning-raspberry-pi/

For future questions on SO try to have a go yourself and then post a question once you get stuck explaining what you've tried and any code you're using. You're more likely to learn more this way.